# Why is this it to represents whole string sometimes, and represents every single char sometimes in Kotlin?

Tags: android, kotlin

In Code A, this ***it*** is the  email `"yole@example.com"`, and in Code B, this ***it*** is every single char `'a'`, `'b'`, `'1'`, `'c'` of `"ab1c"`, why?

**Code A**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    var email: String? = "yole@example.com"
    email?.let { sendEmailTo(it) }  //This it is the email "yole@example.com"
}

fun sendEmailTo(email: String) {
    println("Sending email to $email")
}
```

**Code B**

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("ab1c".filter { it in 'a'..'z' })  //This it is char  'a', 'b,' '1','c' of "ab1c"
}


fun String.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    for (index in 0 until length) {
        val element = get(index)
        if (predicate(element)) sb.append(element)
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

**Added Content**

**Code C**

I will get the same result if I use other extension fun name.

```
fun main(args: Array<String>) {
    println("ab1c".myFun { it in 'a'..'z' })  //This it is char  'a', 'b,' '1','c' of "ab1c"
}

fun String.myFun(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): String {
        val sb = StringBuilder()
        for (index in 0 until length) {
            val element = get(index)
            if (predicate(element)) sb.append(element)
        }
        return sb.toString()
}
```

**Updated Content**

I think what this **it** represents is based the details of these extension fun. right?  So sometimes I need to read the source code of a extension fun!

This **it** in `email?.let { sendEmailTo(it) }` represents `email` because the fun `block` require this.

**Source A**

```
public inline fun <T, R> T.let(block: (T) -> R): R {
    contract {
        callsInPlace(block, InvocationKind.EXACTLY_ONCE)
    }
    return block(this)
}
```

This **it** in `"ab1c".filter { it in 'a'..'z' }` represents char because the fun `predicate` require char in this String object and do a for-loop operation.

**Source B**

```
fun String.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): String {
    val sb = StringBuilder()
    for (index in 0 until length) {
        val element = get(index)
        if (predicate(element)) sb.append(element)
    }
    return sb.toString()
}
```

Comment: You can define your own `String` extension function and have `it` mean whatever you want. The predefined functions are no different.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

These two methods:

```
email?.let { sendEmailTo(it) }  //This it is the email "yole@example.com"
println("ab1c".filter { it in 'a'..'z' })  //This it is char  'a', 'b,' '1','c' of "ab1c"
```

are equivalent to:

```
email?.let(fun (string: String) {
    sendEmailTo(string)
})

println("ab1c".filter(fun (char: Char): Boolean {
    return char in 'a'..'z'
}))
```

as you can see, the `it` refers to `string` in the first method, and refers to `char` in the second. They are two different things, just can be represent by `it` for convenient.

Comment: Thanks! In Code B, why does the system split the string "ab1c" into it?  and why doesn't system split other string such as "vbnm" into it ?

Comment: The system didn't split the string, you split it(in the `String.filter`).

Comment: The string "vbnm" is "split" too, but because the predicate is testing `if the char is in 'a'...'z'`, and "vbnm" are all in 'a'...'z' so it's not be filtered.

Comment: Thanks.  Would you please to see my added content in the question? Why can I get the correct result if I use other extension fun name `myFun` ?  `filter` is normal extension fun just like `myFun` .

Comment: There is nothing to do with the function name. The `for`-loop did the filter.

Comment: Thanks! Do you mean that `println("ab1c".myFun { it in 'a'..'z' })` will return wrong result in Code C ?

Comment: No, it returns "abc" as expected.

Comment: You just implemented the 'filter' by the function body. In fact, your function works just the same as the built-in `String.filter(predicate: (Char) -> Boolean): String`

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my updated content in the question?  I think what this it represents is based the details of extension fun. right?

Comment: Possibly right, the `it` comes from the argument when `block()` or `predicate()` be called, and what the `it` represents is based on the argument you passed in.

Answer (score 5):

As you may know, `it` refers to the single parameter passed into the closure.

`filter` accepts a closure of type `(Char) -> Boolean`, so `it`'s type is `Char`. The reason why `it` is every char in `ab1c` is because how `filter` is implemented. `filter` loops through the sequence and checks each element against the predicate.

`let` on the other hand, is a completely different method, so it is only natural that their behaviours differ. `let` accepts a closure of type `(String) -> Unit` (assuming `sendEmail` returns `Unit`). And all it does is calls the closure with `this` as the parameter, so `it` refers to the thing you called `let` on.

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my added content in the question?

Comment: @HelloCW I saw that. What is the question you want to ask about Code C?

Comment: `filter` is normal extension fun just like `myFun` in my added content in the question. `filter` accept a Char parameter and return Boolean, why will `filter` operate "ab1c" ?

Comment: If there is some code just like `(Char in this) -> Boolean`, it will be more clear

Comment: Oh I see what you mean! You want to make the method declaration clearer, right? I don't think there is a way to make it clearer. There is no other possibility anyway. When you say "filter a string", I automatically think of testing each character against a predicate and removing those that match. You really don't need to think much to understand the purpose of the closure. When there _is_ ambiguity, you can also write documentation. @HelloCW

Comment: Regarding "I will get the same result if I use other extension fun name.", yes that's right. Your `myFun` implementation is one way to implement `filter`. But the point is, `filter` in the standard library is written for you, so you don't have to write it again.

Comment: Thanks! Do you automatically think of testing each character if I use a other extension fun name `myFun` in my added content in the question ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/176759/discussion-between-sweeper-and-hellocw).

Comment: Thanks! Would you please to see my updated content in the question?  I think what this it represents is based the details of extension fun. right?

Comment: @HelloCW yes and what the closure does is  usually documented.